# Why are my Java Projects in Eclipse giving an error on creation?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a new project, I consistently get the follow error message:
"The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Users\damar\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi26EE.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent"

Comment: which jdk installed on your machine?

Comment: Both 15 and 14.0.2

Comment: perhaps related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153079. Try using a lower java version

Comment: How did you get [_JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Minimal Stripped_](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/) to be used to run Eclipse (which is causing this)?